# Getting AWS State machine execution ARN inside the step function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I need to get the ARN of the current execution for my state machine inside the state machine itself. Is it possible?

So can I create a state machine(say from a lambda function) and then take its execution ARN and pass it as a parameter to that machine OR is there any utility available inside the state machine that allows getting the execution ARN for that machine?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

AWS Step Functions released recently a feature called context object.

Now you have access to the execution data through $$ inside the Parameters block.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html

Comment: Is there a way to extract only the id string from the executionId?

Comment: Yes, by getting the "Name" variable.

Answer (score 3):

Step Functions do not currently have this feature, you can however specify your own execution id by specifying a name. This will make the ARN predictable, as it will end up being

arn:aws:states:[AWS Region]:[AWS Account ID]:execution:[Step Function Name]:[The name that you passed to the start-execution call]

[javascript sdk docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/StepFunctions.html#startExecution-property)