# How to give a Lambda function in a state machine access to describe the state machine?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

I've got a `LambdaInvoke` which is part of a state machine. I've specified `input_path="$$.Execution"` to [give it the state machine execution ARN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55729295/96588). Now, **how do I give the `LambdaFunction` belonging to the `LambdaInvoke` access to `states:DescribeExecution` on the `StateMachine` it's part of?**

Both `state_machine.grant_read(lambda_invoke.lambda_function)` and `lambda_function.role.add_to_policy(aws_iam.PolicyStatement(resources=[state_machine.state_machine_arn], actions=["states:DescribeExecution"])` result in CloudFormation failing because of a "Circular dependency between resources". The list of dependencies:

1. The default policy of the role of the Lambda function above
2. The default policy of the role of another Lambda function which *launches* the state machine
3. The Lambda function which launches the state machine
4. The state machine
5. The Lambda function in step 1
6. The stack containing the Lambda function which launches the state machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Irrespective of how a `StateMachine` is started there are 2 different roles, one for your `Lambda` function and one for your `StateMachine`. Lets have a look at sending a message to `sqs` as an example. You could do that directly with your `StateMachine` with `sqs` integration, or you could have a `Lambda` which would do it for you.

**StateMachine Role**

The role given to the `StateMachine` is needed for purposes such as logging, but also depending what integration's you use, such as if you have `sqs:sendMessage` it will need to have an `sqs` policy attached to enable that. If you use `Lambda Functions` in your `StateMachine` you will need to have a policy for `lambda:InvokeFunction`.

**Lambda Function Role**
Lets say you have a `Lambda` which sends a message to `SQS` you don't use the `arn:aws:states:::sqs:sendMessage...` in your definition file, then your `StateMachine` role needs `lambda:InvokeFunction` permissions only, but your `Lambda` needs permissions to `sqs`.

Now for your use case, your `Lambda` needs to have permissions to `states:DescribeExecution`, not `sqs`. If your Lambda function works in the console successfully, and your `StateMachine` has permissions to execute that function all should work.

If you have a `Lambda` launching a `StateMachine` it only needs access to start a `StateMachine`.

**Circular Dependencies Problem**

You don't really have a circular dependency problem you have a permissions problem. Other than creating a new role for every time you would Launch a `StateMachine`, you can't scope a Lambda to one instance, reason being is that there isn't anything you can reference in the condition key context in the `IAM` json so that approach doesn't work. You can limit the `Lambda` to only executions for a particular `StateMachine` but again it would be for all users.

There isn't actually an inherent need for a `Lambda`, launched by a `StateMachine` to describe the very `StateMachine` it was launched from. Reason being is you could simply pass the state of that `StateMachine` to that function anyway.

Comment: In that case the question becomes how to combine the output of other entries in the state machine with the context object (`$$`). I can't find documentation for how the `input_path` argument works in detail.

Comment: In general you really shouldn't use your execution history as state. Any information you need in a given step should be present in your current state. You should refactor for that if that is the case. If you do have a valid use case that you need so much data in your statemachine you should rather externalize it to a DB. Parallel steps merging together will come out as an array https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54105792/parallel-states-merge-the-output-in-step-function

Comment: I've written a [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67512012/96588).