# Get the step function ARN from AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

Assume we have a `calculateLambda`, this AWS Lambda function will be called by two step functions, like this:

```
sf1: start -> calculatelambda(logic1) -> end
sf2: start -> calculateLambda(logic2) -> end
```

To differentiate the Step Functions from the Lambda function, can we get the invoked Step Functions ARN inside of the Lambda function?

Comment: btw, the lambda uses java lanuage

Comment: are you deploying your lambda using some tool like serverless or cloud formation?

Comment: check if this is what your loking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55729295/getting-aws-state-machine-execution-arn-inside-the-step-function